# rails 4 f.fields_for doesn't iterate over my embedded collection

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, fields-for, mongoid4

I am trying to build a simple application where user can post something and attach questions to the post (post.questions).

I am getting problem displaying view in embeds_many scenario. Though I create multiple questions in PostsController # new method, html after rendering only shows one question.

I am using rails4/mongoid/mongodb.

Post.rb:

```
class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :title, type: String
  field :body, type: String

  embeds_many :post_replies
  embeds_many :questions
  belongs_to :poster, class_name: "User"

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
end
```

Quesion.rb.

```
class Question
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  field :q

  embedded_in :post
end
```

PostsController.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

def new 
 @post = Post.new
 3.times{
  post.questions.build
 }
end

 def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, questions_attributes: [:id, :q, :_destroy])
 end

end #end controller
```

Routes.rb
    devise_for :users
    resources :users do
      resources :posts
      resources :addresses
    end 
views/posts/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for([current_user, @post], :html => { :class => "form-horizontal" }) do |f| %>
 -
 -
  <%=f.fields_for @post.questions do|question| %>
    <%= question.text_field :q, :placeholder =>'question', :class => "form-control" %>
  <%end%>
 -
 -
 <%end%>
```

I expect above fields for to display 3 questions but it only shows one question. I tried different ways for fields_for but none worked.

Any help in this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I changed

```
<%=f.fields_for @post.questions do|question| %>
```

to

```
<%=f.fields_for :questions, @post.questions do|question| %>
```

and it worked.

Api ref: here http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for